# what is type of Lotus Notes connector for SharePoint Server 2013?

Tags: 2013, search

what is type of Lotus Notes connector for SharePoint Server 2013?

is it Federated search or Content crawling? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556429(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you install and configured the Lotus notes Connector then SharePoint crawl the content in the Lotus notes Database or individual document(if any).

Check the below article will help you understand it.

[Configure and use the Lotus Notes connector for SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591606(v=office.15).aspx)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262927(v=office.12).aspx